# "More" dropdown menu in TabLayout [Toolbar]

Tags: android-tablayout

I'm working with Tabs (TabLayouts inside AppBarLayouts) and was wondering how to get the more dropdown in tabs like the one's shown in [Google's design spec for Tabs](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/tabs.html#tabs-usage)

Something like this..

[image]

Comment: Surprised! Your question is unanswered for more than a year. Were you able to achieve it? If yes, could you share how you achieved?